# Usage of NOT EXISTS to select ALL members

Tags: mysql, where-clause, exists

I am trying to write an SQL query for a library database using MySQL.
There are two tables `shelf(studentnumber, booknumber)` and `booklist(booknumber,booktitle,language)`. There are 4 different languages in the booklist table entries namely `italian, spanish, hungarian, german`.

**I want to learn the `studentnumbers` who have read all the books in the selected language.**

**Sample Data for tables:**

```
create table shelf(studentnumber INT, booknumber INT); 

INSERT INTO shelf values(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,3)(2,4),(2,5),
                        (2,6),(3,6),(3,7)(3,8),(3,9); 

create table booklist(booknumber INT, booktitle VARCHAR(50), language VARCHAR(10); 

INSERT INTO booklist values(1, 'FirstBook', 'italian'),(2,'SecondBook', 'spanish'),
(3,'ThirdBook','italian'),(4,'FourthBook','german'),(5,'FifthBook','german'),
(6, 'SixthBook','spanish'),(7,'SeventhBook','hungarian'),(8,'EightBook','hungarian'),
(9,'NinthBoo‌​k','hungarian'),(10,'TenthBook','Spanish'),(11,'EleventhBook', 'italian');
```

**Sample Output:**
When you look at the shelf and booklist tables, you see that the student with student no 2 read all the books in german and the student with studentnumber 3 read all the books in hungarian.
But there are no student who have read all the books in italian or spanish.

The last part of the code will be as written below but I couldn't construct the first part, probably it will include `NOT EXISTS`
SELECT booknumber FROM booklist WHERE language='italian';

Comment: Yes, consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle AND THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: Good grief. Edit your question.

Comment: @tpanic Format your question properly.

Comment: Proper DDLs, thanks - so we can replicate the problem. And remove the comments above. Strings require inverted commas

Comment: Done formatting, is it clear enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work nicely for you:

```
select studentnumber 
from shelf s1 join booklist b1 on s1.booknumber=b1.booknumber
group by studentNumber, language
having count(language) >= (
        select count(*) from booklist b2
        where b1.language=b2.language
        group by b2.language)
```

Output:

```
2
3
```

You can also add in first select statement language and count(*) which will provide you with more information (the language they've read along with the number of books) i.e.

```
select studentnumber,language,count(*) 
//rest of code
```

Output

```
2, german, 2
3, hungarian, 3
```

**Update**

To display all students that have read books in a specified language (as requested in the comments), simply add a WHERE clause:

```
select studentnumber
from shelf s1 join booklist b1 on s1.booknumber=b1.booknumber
where language='german'
group by studentNumber, language
having count(language) >= (
        select count(*) from booklist b2
        where b1.language=b2.language
        group by b2.language)
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: @tpanic great, please don't forget to accept the answer then (so the question closes :)

Comment: but I also want to find the studentnumber who read all the books from a language: forexample, in the where clause language='german' and the result should be 2 and where language='hungarian' and the result should be 3. how to make that modification.